# how to use to Javascript Get the button, and when the user clicks on it, execute myFunction in two button

Tags: javascript

```js
// Get the button, and when the user clicks on it, execute myFunction
    document.getElementById("myBtn2").onclick = function() {myFunction()};
    document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = function() {myFunction()};
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("myDrop").classList.toggle("show2");
    }
```

```css
.dropbtn {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
            padding: 16px;
            font-size: 16px;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
            background-color: #3e8e41;
        }

        .dropdown {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            min-width: 160px;
            overflow: auto;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        }

        .dropdown-content a {
            color: black;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
        }

        .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

        .show {display:block;}
        .show2 {display:block;}
```

```html
<h2>Clickable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
    <button id="myBtn" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
    <button id="myBtn2" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div id="myDrop" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above code in this there is two nav and i want to each of clicked as individualy. i try to using two onclick myFuncition Javascript but this is not working. I try to declair two id and that will used in seprately can i do that by same way. Please help on this.Get the button, and when the user clicks on it, execute myFunction

Comment: You need to be more specific on why what you've tried doesn't work.  For instance, why does using two onclick functions not work? What happens? Maybe you're implementing them wrong...

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare twice the same function, however, you can use arguments when calling the functions, so you can target differents elements with the same function structure :

```
document.getElementById("myBtn2").onclick = function() {myFunction("myDropdown", "show")};
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = function() {myFunction("myDrop", "show2")};    
function myFunction(MyId, MyClass) {
  document.getElementById(MyId).classList.toggle(MyClass);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need multiple function to achieve that.

First select all the buttons with [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) then loop through them to attach the event. Invoke/call the function by passing [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword which you can refer inside the event (*click*) handler function to target the relevant dropdown.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".dropbtn").forEach(function(btn){
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() { myFunction(this); });
});

function myFunction(el) {
  el.closest('div').querySelector('.dropdown-content').classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}
.show2 {display:block;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<h2>Clickable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button id="myBtn" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button id="myBtn2" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDrop" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```